# images in email will not display with expresshandlebars and nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I currently have an email template in the form of a .handlebars and the images here don't display in the email even though when I display the .handlebars in firefox, the html and css works perfectly fine.

```
transporter.use('compile', hbs({
      viewEngine: {
        extName: '.handlebars',
        partialsDir: viewPath,
        layoutsDir: viewPath,
        defaultLayout: false,
        },
      viewPath:  viewPath,
      extName: '.handlebars',
    }))
```

I think the problem is with using nodemailer-handlebars instead of nodemailer-express-handlebars, but when I used nodemailer-express-handlebars, the directory would act weirdly. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I want to use viewEngine: 'express-handlebars', but I would get the error no such file or directory main.handlebars. Also, the images are located under the same folder and I just use
`<a href="" target=""><img src="./images/instagram.png"></a>`.

Edit2: Here is more of my code for :

```
viewPath = path.resolve("./utils/");
    transporter.use('compile', hbs({
      viewEngine: {
        defaultLayout: false,
      },
      // viewEngine: 'express-handlebars',
      viewPath:  viewPath,
    }))
    let mailOptions = {
      from: 'email1Here', //our account
      // to: tutorUser.email,
      to: 'email2Here',
      subject: 'Testing',
      text: 'success. the email works',
      template: 'newEnrolledStudent'
    };
```

I also made the images in a public folder since the emails are being sent on the server side.

Edit3: So I have tried putting my images in a public folder in server and done app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/public`));. I also switched over to a .ejs nodemailer but images also don't seem to appear if I have them linked with a file path, but if I use a weburl, it works fine.  Any help would be greatly appreciated and I can provide any clarification if needed.